# Using Javascript I want a button to show or hide a div by changing the css

Tags: javascript, html, css, controls

Using JavaScript, I want a button to show or hide a div by changing the CSS.

HTML:

```
<div id="bottomContainer">
    <div id="count" class="count">...</div>
    <div id="visualizations>...</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bottomContainer {
    display: block;
}
```

I want to use javascript to do the following

[button]

When button is clicked Javascript changes the CSS for bottomContainer to the following

```
.bottomContainer {
     display: none;
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Please use the search.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a number of ways.  With vanilla JS, you would do something like:

```
document.getElementById('myButtonId').addEventListener('click', function () {
    document.getElementById('bottomContainer').style.display = "none";
}
```

This is just one of a few ways.  You could also make a css rule for a `.hide` class that has the `display: none` rule, or do this with jQuery's `.hide()` method, or any number of framework-based means.

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you only want the button to hide the container and not toggle its visibility.

```
<button onClick="document.getElementById('bottomContainer').style.display = 'none';">Click me</button>
```

Comment: This worked, I should mention that after using this I wanted to control multiple Div's with one button so I did the following

Comment: <button onClick="myfunction()">Click me</button>

Comment: The javascript I used was 

<script>
function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('id1').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('id2').style.display = 'none';
}
</script>